# Generating New Cell with Each Button Press

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

new to Swift 2 here, and I have a quick question. Haven't found any relevant answers yet but I am trying to make the table view cell generate a cell for each lap time every time the lap button is pressed (similar to the apple stopwatch). The problem that I'm having is how do I transfer my cellContent array items into individual cells in a table view. Thanks in advance!

```
var startTime = NSTimeInterval()
var timer = NSTimer()
var cellContent:[String] = []

func updateTime() {

    let currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

    //Find the difference between current time and start time.

    var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = currentTime - startTime

    //calculate the minutes in elapsed time.

    let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60.0)

    elapsedTime -= (NSTimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

    //calculate the seconds in elapsed time.

    let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)

    elapsedTime -= NSTimeInterval(seconds)

    //find out the fraction of milliseconds to be displayed.

    let fraction = UInt8(elapsedTime * 100)

    //add the leading zero for minutes, seconds and millseconds and store them as string constants

    let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
    let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
    let strFraction = String(format: "%02d", fraction)

    //concatenate minuets, seconds and milliseconds as assign it to the UILabel

    timeDisplay.text = "\(strMinutes)"+":"+"\(strSeconds)"+":"+"\(strFraction)"

} //changes time on display

@IBAction func lapButton(sender: AnyObject) //adds time to array
{
    cellContent.append(timeDisplay.text!)
}

@IBAction func pause(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer.invalidate()
} //pauses timer

@IBAction func stop(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer.invalidate()
    timeDisplay.text = "00:00:00"

} //stops timer

@IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {

    if !timer.valid
    {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    }

} //starts timer if inactive

@IBOutlet var timeDisplay: UILabel!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return cellContent.count //need to revise
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = cellContent[indexPath.row] //need to revise

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a little nervous about answering because it seems like my solution to your problem is so simple that it must be wrong, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

I think that in your `lapButton` function you need to call `UITableView`'s `reloadData()` function described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW61). As you can see there's some other fun stuff you can do reloading the table, like adding animations and such.

I hope this helps!

P.S. Where is your `UITableView`? I don't actually see a reference to it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should inform UITableView that datasource data has been changed and table view has to update a total number of cells and visible cells.

The easiest way is to call `reloadData`:

```
@IBAction func lapButton(sender: AnyObject) //adds time to array
{
    cellContent.append(timeDisplay.text!)
    yourTableView.reloadData()
}
```

but more effectively is to use [insertRowsAtIndexPaths: animation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:)